# Integrate Sencha Touch 2.x with Twitter REST API v1.1

Tags: twitter, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

How to use the REST API of twitter last version with sencha touch 2.x ?

Answer (score 0):

To make requests for some remote api you can use `Ext.Ajax.request();`

```
Ext.Ajax.request({  
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
        id: 'someId'
    },
    success: function ( repsonse ) {

    },
    failure: function ( response ) {

    }
});
```

But be aware of Same-origin policy.